# How to merge object Arrays by adding index then sort map based on the same index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to merge two or more object Arrays which can be added randomly and give each object an adding index and then `map` them in sorted index order.

Couldn't really find an example out there that does this specifc thing, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
  const [objOne, setObjOne] = useState("")
  const [objOneArray, setObjOneArray] = useState([])

  const [objTwo, setObjTwo] = useState("")
  const [objTwoArray, setObjTwoArray] = useState([])

  const combinedObjs = objOneArray.concat(objTwoArray);


  const AddObjOne = (e) => {
    setObjOneArray((old) => [...old, {printOne: objOne}]);
  };

  const AddObjTwo = (e) => {
    setObjTwoArray((old) => [...old, {printTwo: objTwo}]);
  };

  <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={(e) setObjOne(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={AddObjOne}>Add One</button>

    <input type="text" onChange={(e) setObjTwo(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={AddObjTwo}>Add Two</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    {combinedObjs.map((obj, index) => {
      if (obj.printOne)
        return (
          <div className="bg-red-500" key={index}>
            <p>{obj.printOne}</p>
          </div>
        );

      if (obj.printTwo)
        return (
          <div className="bg-green-500" key={index}>
            <p>{obj.printTwo}</p>
          </div>
        );
    })}
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use 1 state with an array and add all the data in that array so it will be always an insertion order. Any reason to maintain 2 specific arrays?

Comment: No there isn't any specific reason, I was just trying around to make it work on my own. But I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

Using one objectArray, instead of merging two worked as I intended.